# Removed node module but still looking for it?

Tags: react-native, npm

I installed phantomjscloud by mistake on my react native app and now I'm getting an error saying, "Unable to resolve module 'fs'". I've removed, uninstalled, unlinked, deleted the node_module folder, cleared the cache, cloned the repo to a completely new folder, etc. I don't know what else to do. Even when I ran it in a new folder in a different directory, it still had the same error with the same exact directory, even though that directory doesn't exist anymore.

I'm all out of idea on how to fix this...

Comment: remove that particular package from your package.json

Comment: do exactly what it hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as it says:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Now check in **package.json** that `phantomjscloud` should not be written. If yes then **remove it and save**.

Now

```
npm install 

npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: Thank you. I had followed those steps already but didn't realize I was getting an error while resetting cache. I had to kill my packager first and then the reset worked. Thank you!